# Inno Setup Remember selected setup type when Uninstallable=no

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am creating an Inno Setup installer that is a little non traditional. I am setting `Uninstallable=no` but I still need to be able to remember what the user selected for the type of install if they reinstall in the future. I thought about writing the type out to a file which I was able to do. I am not sure how to set the type when the installer is run the next time however. Here is my code for storing the type.

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if (CurStep = ssDone) then
    SaveStringToFile('{app}\type.dat', WizardSetupType(false), false);
end;
```

I know how to read this back in, but I am not sure how to set the type.

Edit:

Here is the new code

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  { We need to manually store and restore the install type since Uninstallable=no }
  if (CurPageID = wpSelectComponents) then
    WizardForm.TypesCombo.ItemIndex := GetIniInt('Settings', 'InstallType', 0, 0, 3, ExpandConstant('{app}\settings.ini'));
  if (CurPageID = wpInstalling) then
    SetIniInt('Settings', 'InstallType', WizardForm.TypesCombo.ItemIndex, ExpandConstant('{app}\settings.ini'));
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save `WizardForm.TypesCombo.ItemIndex` instead of the `WizardSetupType` and set it back when restoring the selection.

After restoring the `WizardForm.TypesCombo.ItemIndex` you have to call the `WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange` to update the components selection.

---

I'd also suggest you use INI file functions [`SetIniInt`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_setiniint) and [`GetIniInt`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getiniint) instead of the `SaveStringToFile`.

---

Store:

```pascal
SetIniInt('Settings', 'InstallType', WizardForm.TypesCombo.ItemIndex,
          ExpandConstant('{app}\settings.ini'));
```

Restore:

```pascal
WizardForm.TypesCombo.ItemIndex :=
  GetIniInt('Settings', 'InstallType', 0, 0, 3, ExpandConstant('{app}\settings.ini'));
{ The OnChange is not called automatically when ItemIndex is set programmatically. }
{ We have to call it to update components selection. }
WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange(WizardForm.TypesCombo);
```

---

*For an explanation of the last code line, see [What does it mean if we type WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange(WizardForm.TypesCombo) in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63135577/850848)*