# What does it mean WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange(WizardForm.TypesCombo) in Inno Setup?

Tags: delphi, inno-setup, onchange

In documentation for `TComboBox = class(TCustomComboBox)` there's this:

`property OnChange: TNotifyEvent; read write;`, where `TNotifyEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject);`.

Judging from that `OnChange` has no parameters, only the returned value. In Delphi `OnChange` event has the `Sender: TObject` parameter. Why is that allowed to type the following then and what does it mean if it's not the same as `Sender: TObject`?

```
WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange(WizardForm.TypesCombo)
```

*(taken from [Inno Setup Remember selected setup type when Uninstallable=no](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35710972/850848#35717398))*

Comment: `WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange` is a property of type `TNotifyEvent`. This is a procedure having one parameter of type `TObject`. So if `OnChangeHandler` is a procedure taking one argument of type `TObject`, you can assign it to this property. And if you call it, either by using its own name `OnChangeHandler` or the property it has been assigned to, `WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange`, you have to give it one `TObject` value, such as `WizardForm.TypesCombo`. This works just as in Delphi, except in Delphi `TNotifyEvent` isn't a regular procedure, but a method procedure.

Comment: Basically, `WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange` is a procedural pointer, that is, a variable that contains (the address of) a procedure. So `WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange := OnChangeHandler` tells the `TypesCombo` to call the `OnChangeHandler` every time it is changed. And `WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange(WizardForm.TypesCombo)` is the same thing as `OnChangeHandler(WizardForm.TypesCombo)`: it calls this procedure with `WizardForm.TypesCombo` as its argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange` is an event handler that is called by VCL (Delphi GUI library used to build Inno Setup), when user changes the selected item in `TypesCombo`. In Inno Setup source code that [event handler is assigned](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-6_0_5/Projects/Wizard.dfm#L425) to [`TWizardForm.TypesComboChange` method](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-6_0_5/Projects/Wizard.pas#L2631-L2651). That implementation updates the selected setup components based on the newly selected setup type.

But if you change the selected setup type by assigning `WizardForm.TypesCombo.ItemIndex` in Pascal Script code in your Inno Setup script, the `TWizardForm.TypesComboChange` won't get called. So the setup components won't get updated and the installer wizard GUI will get into an inconsistent state. To force the setup component selection update, you have to trigger the call to the `TWizardForm.TypesComboChange` manually in your Pascal Script code. You cannot call the method directly, as its a private method, not exposed in Inno Setup Pascal Script. But as the `WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange` holds a pointer to the method, you can (and should) call it via the pointer.

---

`WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange` is of type `TNotifyEvent` so, it has the same amount of parameters. The `TNotifyEvent` event handler type declaration specifies that the handler takes one `TObject` argument. That argument will contain pointer to the component for which the event handler is called, when it is triggered by VCL in a response to a user action. That's for the case, the event handler is shared by multiple components. What is not the case here, and the `TWizardForm.TypesComboChange` actually does not use the argument value at all. But for consistency and future compatibility, it's good to call it the way VCL would – so with `TWizardForm.TypesCombo`.

And that what that code does:

```pascal
WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange(WizardForm.TypesCombo);
```

As the `WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange` equals to `WizardForm.TypesComboChange`, the above code is the same as calling:

```
WizardForm.TypesComboChange(WizardForm.TypesCombo);
```